# WPF + WCF + MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wcf

Самостоятельно не смог найти понятный для меня пример приложения WPF + WCF + MVVM, если у кого есть такие ссылки, пожалуйста поделитесь.

Или своими словами, что тут будет являться моделью , что вью-моделью.

Сейчас все написано без использования паттерна.

Есть **сервис**,

там получается есть класс `DataContext.Person` ,  т.е. сама таблица Персон

есть допустим

```
[DataContract]      
public class ExtendetPerson     
{           
public Person;           
public string AdditionalInfo;      
}
```

Далее в нем описан интерфейс

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IMyService
{
        [OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(MyCantGetException))]
        List<Person> GetPersons();
}
```

и прочие функции для одного персона, для расширреной версии персона, сохранение , удаление.И конечно реализация этого интерфейса.

В **клиенте** эти функции вызываются в кодбехайнде. Типа так..

```
using (var db = currentOption.ClientFactory.CreateClient())
{
   var persons = db.GetPersons();
```

Как вот это переделать в MVVM...

Comment: А что тут думать? WCF — типичная модель

Comment: А вызывать модельные функции вcode behind неправильно.

Comment: 1) Т.е. в проекте клиента у меня не будет файла с моделью Person?

Comment: 2) А для какой-то более сложной вкладки (к примеру список Persons, для каждого Person выводить список заказов, напротив имени в списке  индикатор в зависимости от статуса последнего заказа) мы создаем в клиенте модель на основе WCF моделей?
Типа `class SuperModel`
`{`
 `public ObservableCollection<Persons>...{get;set;}`
`public ObservableCollection<Orders>..{get;set;}`
`public ObservableCollection<Status>..{get;set;}`
`}`
То есть просто объявляем какие модели будут использоватся.
А далее делаем `class SuperViewModel` где уже вызываем "базовые" модельные функции ? ?
 db.GetPersons();..

Comment: А что вы называете _клиентом_?

Comment: Клиентом называю WPF приложение

Comment: Окей, но модель-то часть приложения. Тогда непонятно, почему вы пишете _в проекте клиента у меня не будет файла с моделью Person_. Модель -- точно такая же часть приложения, как и V, и VM.

Comment: Но вы же писали _WCF — типичная модель_ , я и подумал, раз модель это у нас то, что мы описываем в сервисе, то в приложении(проекте) с WPF мы не будем делать класс модели, а сразу будем вызывать функции сервиса из VM